# Order of the legend of drizzt

Tags: suggested-order, legend-of-drizzt

I've been listening to the Legend of Drizzt series and am currently on *The Orc King*. Now my problem is in the last book, *The Two Swords*, it ended on the note of going to Gauntlgrym. So I started *The Orc King* thinking it would start from there, but no: it seems to be 100 years in the future. Am I reading in the wrong order? Thanks

Comment: [Author suggested reading order](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10152944925124811&id=54142479810)

Comment: You are facing a time skip that will be covered later. Carry on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113257/order-of-the-legend-of-drizzt#comment272218_113257) *The Orc King* is the correct book to read after *The Two Swords*. I do understand why you are confused though. The events of prologue of *The Orc King* take place at a significantly later time than the ending of *The Two Swords*, but chapter 1 of *The Orc King* takes place immediately after the events *The Two Swords*.